# how to normalize histogram

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, distribution

I ma creating the exponential distribution using inverse method. I want to normalize histogram. How can I do it?

This is my code

```
N=100;
Lambda=2;
r=rand(N,1);
X=-log(1-r)/Lambda;
hist(X), colormap(bone);

t = 0:0.01:5;
pdf=Lambda*exp(-Lambda*t);
hold on, plot(t,pdf,'LineWidth',2)
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by normalizing a histogram

Comment: You multiply each element with a given number, `pdf=c*Lambda*exp(-Lambda*t);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The histogram should be normalized to **unit area** so that it can be compared with the theoretical pdf. To normalize to unit area you need to divide by the number of samples and by the bin width:

```
N = 100;
Lambda=2;
r = rand(N,1);
X = -log(1-r)/Lambda;
[hy, hx] = hist(X); %/ get histogram values
hy = hy/numel(X)/(hx(2)-hx(1)); %//normalize histogram
bar(hx, hy) %// plot histogram
t = 0:0.01:5;
pdf = Lambda*exp(-Lambda*t);
hold on, plot(t,pdf,'LineWidth',2) %// plot pdf
```

[image]

Or use the new [`histogram`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) function (introduced in R2014b), which **automatically normalizes** according to the specified normalization option:

```
N = 100;
Lambda=2;
r = rand(N,1);
X = -log(1-r)/Lambda;
histogram(X, 'Normalization', 'pdf') %// plot normalized histogram
t = 0:0.01:5;
pdf = Lambda*exp(-Lambda*t);
hold on, plot(t,pdf,'LineWidth',2) %// plot pdf
```

Comment: For lay readers such as myself, **unit area** means the total area of the curve must be equal to 1 (unity).